# using scheme-relative URL in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap

I'm using `.get()`  to get html that include scheme relative. (like `<a href="//example.com/pic.gif">` )
phonegap don't recognize the `//` and need `http/s`.
Any tip for auto fix for that?

```
  $.getJSON('http://www.example.com/jsonAPI.php?action=post&postid='+id, function(data) {
    //alert("success"); 
    $('#setTitle').html(data.post.title);
  })  
  .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
  //.done(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

The double forward slash `//` is shorthand for whatever url scheme the browser/webview is currently using. In PhoneGap, this is generally file:// -- so this won't work in PhoneGap.

One option might be to replace `//` with `https://` in the response, something like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.example.com/jsonAPI.php?action=post&postid='+id, function(data) { 
  var title = data.post.title.replace(/href=[\"\']\/\//, "https://");
  $('#setTitle').html(data.post.title);
})  
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
```